# VsTsc task unsupported by toolsversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I tried to build my project however suddenly I am getting an error on visual studio 2013 here is the problem I am having.  I have not changed anything since last night, however when I hopped on today it seems that this popped up https://gyazo.com/d170bdfc18f9896003978ced330a1c71

Here is the error log that I am getting in VS

> Error 2   The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.    Arecibo
>
> Error 1   The "ToolsVersion" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

Also here is my project file is this makes sense.  At first it was complaining about not having the correct typescript version.

and here is my cs proj file http://pastebin.com/kA1yiwPQ,  stackoverflow does not allow me to exceed a certain amount of characters so I had to resort to pastebin

Answer (score 2):

Try repairing the TypeScript Tools package - go to the `Control Panel` > `Programs & Features`, and choose "TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 xxxx", choose `Change` and then in the installer click `Repair`.

I had this issue just now in Visual Studio 2015, after recreating a brand new ASP.NET Core project, and doing the repair fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS2015 after dumping 2013 for it's lack of integration.
I got past this problem by removing a previously installed TypeScript package for VS2013.

As always, be sure to restart VS2015 after doing the uninstall.